# random numbers without repeating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, random

Actually I've already found a working loop here. but the problem is i don't know how to use it properly (noob coder here :D). what i want to do is display a random question each click until all 20 of them has been used up. but my code below restarts each click and i cant make the counter work. i hope someone can help me :)

```
    Dim questions() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Dim xTemp As Integer = 0
    Dim xRndNo As New List(Of Integer)
    While Not xRndNo.Count = 20
        xTemp = xGenerator.Next(0, 20)
        If xRndNo.Contains(xTemp) Then
            Continue While
        Else
            xRndNo.Add(xTemp)
            Label1.Text = "question no.:" & xTemp
            Label2.Text = questions(xTemp)
            Label3.text = xRndNo.Count 'a hidden counter 
        End If
    End While
    objStreamReader.Close()
```

Comment: This code initialized the array of 20 question in random order. All you need to do is to keep an index of the current question, display it and increment the index at the button click until you reach the limit (20)

Comment: thats what i was trying to do. i made label 3 for that purpose, but it is stucked on 20 and wont change

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly fine. I ran it and it didn't get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly where you are getting stuck, but this might help.

Write your code like this:

```
Dim questions() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
Dim randomQuestions = _
    questions _
        .OrderBy(Function (x) xGenerator.Next()) _
        .ToArray()
```

Now you just have to keep track of a single counter to index `randomQuestions` and then update your text fields and increment it each time a person answers a question.